# how to fix this #0 0xfeea5b41 in strcpy () from /lib/libc.so.1

Tags: c, file-handling

I want to read a file and store it in a list. I did do that but when I am using gdb I get this error:

```
#0  0xfeea5b41 in strcpy () from /lib/libc.so.1.
```

Here is the code:

```
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  /*declare and initialise variable */
  char array[10][150], buffer[150];
  //message =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
  int i = 0;
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");
  if (fp == 0)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Input not valid\n");
      exit (1);
    }
  /*stores and prints the data from the string */
  int counter = 0;
  while (fgets (buffer, 150, fp))
    {
      strcpy (array[i], buffer);
      //printf(" %s",message[i]);
      i++;
      counter++;
    }
  fclose (fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There seem no bad point except the bad indent, absence of `#include` and comparing point `fp` against integer `0`. What is the contents of your input file?

Comment: `i++;` should be checked for range as it indexes up to 10 elements. If there are more than 10 file reads, you'll break the array.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong here.

1. If more than 10 lines are present, you will overrun `array`, and the `strcpy` will try copying to an invalid location. I expect that is the cause of the bug.
2. `fopen` returns a pointer (so `NULL`) on error, rather than 0.
3. You are not checking the return value of `fgets`; it returns `NULL` on error.
4. Incrementing `counter` and `i` seems redundant as they both will have the same value.
5. You have not `#include`d the relevant include files so your C compiler will not pick up the correct function prototypes. You need: `#include <stdio.h>`, `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <string.h>`. You would pick this up by compiling with `gcc -Wall`.

Comment: `0` is a null pointer constant, so `fp == 0` is technically fine (it might mislead human readers, though).

Comment: `exit(1)` is not portable, though: The only standard exit values are `0` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` for success and `EXIT_FAILURE` for error.

Comment: @melpomene really? http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exit.html says *"The value of `status` may be 0, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, `EXIT_FAILURE`, or any other value, though only the least significant 8 bits (that is, `status & 0377`) shall be available to a waiting parent process"* - that looks to me like values other than those three are permitted.

Comment: That's POSIX. I was talking about standard C. And sure, other values may be permitted but their interpretation depends on the system you're on. For example, `exit(1)` might represent success while `exit(2)` triggers a core dump ... or something.

Comment: @melpomene: 7.20.4.5 para 3 says return codes other than those three are implementation defined. However, as both the successful and unsuccessful cases are also 'implementation defined', I don't think the other values are any less portable!

Comment: There's at least one real system out there where `exit(1)` indicates success, not an error. That's why I prefer `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`.

Comment: @melpomene, fair enough (though `exit(0)` is defined by the standard to indicate success too).